# Qual a diferença entre col-lg-* , col-md-* e col-sm-* no Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, grid

Faz um bom tempo que uso o `Bootstrap` trabalhei com quase todas as versões. Normalmente para estruturar as minhas aplicações uso o sistema de `grid` do Bootstrap, `row` para criar linhas e `col-` pra colunas.

Gostaria de saber  :

- A diferença entre `col-lg-*` , `col-md-*` e `col-sm-*`
- Em que circunstâncias devem ser usadas
- No caso de uso inapropriado desse elementos que problemas poderão surgir ?

Comment: da uma olhada na explicação da [w3cschools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp), lá tem exemplos e o try it yourself.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Na própria documentação do Bootstrap há uma tabela comparativa entre as classes de grid.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, a classe `.col-xs-*` definem o grid para dispositivos com largura de tela inferior à 768px. A classe `.col-sm-*` define para telas superiores à 768px. A classe `.col-md-*` define para telas superiores à 970px e a classe `.col-lg-*` para telas superiores à 1200px. Seu uso basicamente é para definir diferentes grids para seu elemento, com base no tamanho do *display* de seu usuário.

Por exemplo, você pode desejar exibir um setor de seu site em duas colunas em monitores, definindo a classe `.col-sm-6` para cada. Porém, em dispositivos de tela pequena, como celular, duas colunas pode não ser o ideal, deixando o conteúdo espremido e pequeno, com isso você pode definir que nesses dispositivos, ao invés de duas colunas, este setor seja em apenas uma coluna, com a classe `.col-xs-12`.

Basicamente você está dizendo ao navegador: se a tela do usuário possuir largura maior ou igual a 768px, exiba esta `div` ocupando 6 das 12 colunas do meu grid. Já, se a largura for inferior à 768px, exiba-a ocupando as 12 das 12 colunas do grid.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">...</div>
```

É uma funcionalidade muito útil principalmente quando se tem, por exemplo, uma lista de produtos em uma loja virtual. Você consegue definir quantos produtos aparecem por linha em cada *display* configurando o tamanho da coluna.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">{Produto}</div>
```

Assim, apareceriam 1 produto para *extra small devices*, ocupando 12 de 12 colunas do grid, 3 produtos em *small devices*, ocupando 4 de 12 colunas, 4 produtos em *medium devices*, ocupando 3 de 12 colunas e 6 produtos em *large devices*, ocupando 2 de 12 colunas.

> **Nota pessoal:**  O sistema de grid é, da forma apresentada, a principal funcionalidade do Bootstrap implementando a filosofia *Mobile First* e responsividade. Se faz tempo que já o utiliza e não sabia tal diferença, recomendo estudar um pouco mais a documentação antes de continuar ou buscar outro método de estudo. (Tome isso como uma crítica positiva)

Comment: Em adição, atualmente o bootstrap 4 conta com mais um argumento para controlar o comportamento do grid system. Seja, col-xl-* , para extra large devices. Então os novos argumentos são: ``.col-* (extra small devices - < 576px)``, ``.col-sm-* (small devices  >= 576px)``, ``.col-md-* (medium devices >= 768px)``, ``.col-lg-* (large devices >= 992px)``, ``.col-xl-* (xlarge devices >= 1200px).``

Answer (score 7):

<sup>**Agora com a versão oficial do Bootstrap sendo a `versão 4`, acredito que a resposta mereça um update.**</sup>

Segue o link da documentação oficial do **grid da verão 4**: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Na imagem abaixo repare que em *vermelho* marquei os novos modelos de fracionamento do grid, que agora conta com a classe `.col-xl-` para telas maiores que `1200px` e com a classe `col-`, que pode ser usada simplesmente como `class="col"` para ocupar 100% da largura caso não tenha outra `col` ao seu lado, ou `class="col-6"` caso queira que ela tenha apenas 50% da largura da tela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Mais detalhes**

O grid da **versão 3** era baseado em `float:left` para posicionar as colunas lado a lado. Mas na **versão 4** o grid é feito com `display:flex` o que facilita bastante os alinhamentos verticais e deixa tudo ainda mais responsivo.

A classe `col` é definida dessa forma pelo fato do *container* pai a `.row` ser com `display:flex`

```
.col {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1; /* isso faz com que a largura fique "autimática" */
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Sobre o `flex-grow`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow

Veja esse exemplo abaixo construindo o grid apenas com a class="col", repare que se tiver `2` `divs` com `class="col"` cada uma assume 50% do espaço. Se tiverem `3` `divs` cada uma assume `1/3` do espaço.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
<div class="col border">
  div class=col 50%
</div>
<div class="col border">
  div class=col 50%
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
<div class="col border">
  div class=col 33,33%
</div>
<div class="col border">
  div class=col 33,33%
</div>
<div class="col border">
  div class=col 33,33%
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-6 border">
  class=col-6
</div>
<div class="col-3 border">
  class=col-3
</div>
<div class="col-3 border">
  class=col-3
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Quando o elemento tem a classe `col-n°` quer dizer que ela sempre vai ter essa largura `n°` independente da largura da tela, então uma `div` `class="col-6"` sempre vai ocupar 50% da largura da tela, na importa se a tela tem 200px ou 2000px.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS:**

O restante do comportamento do grid na **versão 4** é condizente com a resposta do @AndersonCarlosWoss e ainda segue esses princípios de fracionamento como ele explicou na outra resposta.

Sendo que

Isso:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">{Produto}</div>
```

Agora é isso:

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">{Produto}</div>
```

Como dito, qualquer `col-xs-` **deixou de existir**, e agora deve ser substituido por `col-` *número*.

Answer (score 4):

São atributos do bootstrap que definirão o tamanho do grid, em relação ao tamanho do dispositivo, são `breakpoints` :

`col-xs-*` extrasmall `< 768 px`

`col-sm-*` small `>= 768 px`

`col-md-*` medium `>= 992 px`

`col-lg-*` large `>= 1200 px`

Em relação a pergunta :

Em que circunstâncias devem ser usadas ?

Por se tratar de layout, é amplo responder, mas no geral quando vc quer um grid que se adapte a esses padrões de `breakpoints`.

E o uso inapropriado, o único problema é no seu layout.