# Alinhar dados de tabelas em campos diferentes

Tags: html5, css3, angular, bootstrap-4

Estou trabalhando com um card que vai funcionar para retornar dados como (dia de hoje, mês atual, dia de ontem e enfim), mas gostaria de deixar o dia igual a imagem, não consegui usando tabelas, segue o código:

```css
.mes-setado {
  letter-spacing: 15px;
  font-size: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 150px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: -5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.ano-setado {
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-size: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 150px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: -5px;
}

.dia-setado {
  font-size: 80px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.simple {
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 2.5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.values {
  font-size: 25px;
  align-content: right;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10.5px;
}

.tabela {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: inline;
}

.info {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
  margin-top: 10.5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 row justify-content-center">
  <nb-card accent="info">
    <nb-card-body>
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="container">
          <table class="tabela">
            <td class="dia-setado">23</td> <br>
            <td class="mes-setado">SET</td> <br>
            <td class="ano-setado">2019</td>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="info"></div>
      <div>
        <div class="simple">Digitados</div>
        <div class="values">310.800</div>
        <div class="simple">Pagos</div>
        <div class="values">128.100</div>
      </div>
      <nb-progress-bar status="info" [value]="30"></nb-progress-bar>
    </nb-card-body>
  </nb-card>
</div>
```

[image: Deve ficar assim]

Comment: No que exatamente está com problema? A saída gerada ficou bem próxima a esperada. Aliás, os elementos `<nb-card>`, `<nb-card-body>`, etc não são nativos do HTML, o que sugere que está utilizando algo a mais que apenas HTML 5 e CSS 3.

Comment: O número está muito cima, não está alinhado com mês/ano. Perdão, editei agora colocando Bootstrap e Angular.

Comment: Sugiro também [edit] e listar quais são as diferenças que está buscando corrigir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja que algumas mudanças podem ser feitas apenas ajustando o CSS.
Tente desta forma aqui tbm, embora o CSS fique mais comprido (aparentemente) mas vc pode utilizar suas próprias configurações e não ficar preso ao do Bootstrap.

```css
body {
    line-height: 1 !important;
}

tr {
 width: 30% !important;
}

.dia-setado {
  font-size: 80px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.mes-setado {
  letter-spacing: 12px;
  font-size: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: -2px;
  margin-bottom: -18px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.ano-setado {
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-size: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: -2px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.simple {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-right: 2.5px;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.values {
  font-size: 25px;
  align-content: right;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 1.5px;
}

.tabela {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: inline;
}

.info {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
  margin-top: 0.5px;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 5px !important;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9{
 position: relative !important;
 width: 100% !important;
 max-height: 5rem;
 padding-right: 2px !important;
 padding-left: 2px !important;
}

.col-md-2{
 max-width: 12.3rem !important;
}

.col-md-5{
 max-width: 6rem !important;
}

.col-md-7{
 max-width: 6rem !important;
}

.col-md-10{
 max-width: 12.3rem !important;
}

.card {
    width: 18rem!important;
    border: 0px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125) !important;
}

.card-body {
    padding: 5px !important;
        padding-top: 5px !important;
        padding-right: 5px !important;
        padding-bottom: 5px !important;
        padding-left: 5px !important;
}

.row {
    display: -ms-flexbox !important;
    display: flex !important;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap !important;
    flex-wrap: wrap !important;
    margin-right: -15px !important;
    margin-left: 0px !important;
 max-width: 11.7rem !important;
}
```

```html
<body>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2 row justify-content-center">
  <div class="card">
  <div class="card " style="max-width: 180px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
  <div class="tabela">
            <div class="dia-setado">23</div>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
  <div class="tabela">
            <div class="mes-setado">SET</div>
            <div class="ano-setado">2019</div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
 </div>
   
      <div class="info"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
  <div class="simple">Digitados</div>
        <div class="values">310.800</div>
        <div class="simple">Pagos</div>
        <div class="values">128.100</div>
        
    </div>
      <nb-progress-bar status="info" [value]="30"></nb-progress-bar>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Vou ver se consigo dessa forma, preciso colocar mais dois cards. Um é outro formato, o layout muda ai está me mudando a largura do card.

Answer (score 1):

Se vc está usando tabela vc tem que usar `rowspan/colspan` conforme precisar, além disso vc não deve montar a tabela com vc fez, jogando `TDs` dentro de uma `Table`... E não coloque `display: inline;` em uma tabela! A tabela tem que ser `display:table;`, ou então use `divs` e não uma `table`. Recomendo que leia isso [Duas celulas de dados para uma de cabeçalho](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/369229/duas-celulas-de-dados-para-uma-de-cabe%c3%a7alho/369232#369232) e tb a esse documentação que tem uns exemplos práticos https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Além disso vc vai precisa tratar o `line-height` para o espaçamento vertical ficar mais "compacto" para isso eu coloquei `line-hiegt` de `100%`, ou seja, 100% da altura do próprio caractere a grosso modo.

***OBS:*** tudo que vc colocou e que não precisava como `float:left` etc eu deixei comentado... repare na quantidade de coisa ;)

```css
.mes-setado {
    letter-spacing: 15px;
    font-size: 35px;
    /* width: 100%; */
    /* padding-left: 150px; */
    /* float: right; */
    /* margin-right: -5px; */
    /* margin-bottom: 10px; */
}

.ano-setado {
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 35px;
    /* width: 100%; */
    /* padding-left: 150px; */
    /* float: right; */
    /* margin-right: -5px; */
    line-height: 100%;
}

.dia-setado {
    font-size: 80px;
    /* padding-top: 10px; */
    /* width: 100%; */
    line-height: 100%;
}

.simple {
    text-align: right;
    /* margin-right: 2.5px; */
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.values {
    font-size: 25px;
    /* align-content: right; */
    text-align: right;
    /* width: 100%; */
    padding-bottom: 10.5px;
}

.tabela {
    /* width: 100%; */
    margin-top: 10px;
    /* display: inline; */
}

.info {
    /* width: 100%; */
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    margin-top: 10.5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 row justify-content-center">
    <nb-card accent="info">
        <nb-card-body>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="container">
                    <table class="tabela">
                        <tr>
                            <td rowspan="2" class="dia-setado">23</td> 
                            <td class="ano-setado">2019</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="ano-setado">2019</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="info"></div>
            <div>
                <div class="simple">Digitados</div>
                <div class="values">310.800</div>
                <div class="simple">Pagos</div>
                <div class="values">128.100</div>
            </div>
            <nb-progress-bar status="info" [value]="30"></nb-progress-bar>
        </nb-card-body>
    </nb-card>
</div>
```

Comment: Consegui! Valeu!

Comment: @WandersonBueno  legal que deu certo ai!! Se vc acha que a resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marca-la como aceita nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas ao lado da resposta ;)

Comment: Só mais uma dúvida, eu quero gerar mais dois cards desse, queria que ficasse um do lado do outro, mas do jeito que tá, eles ficam indo pra baixo, sabe algo que possa usar?

Comment: Nessa sua div `<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 row justify-content-center">`  ela tem que estar dentro de uma outra `div` com a classe **Row**. E coloque assim e veja se resolve  <div class="col-4">. 
@WandersonBueno Da uma olhada nessa outra resposta que vai te ajudar a entender o Grid do Bootstrap https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/182188/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-col-lg-col-md-e-col-sm-no-bootstrap/352550#352550

Comment: Consegui por um do lado do outro, mas estão colados. A dúvida agora além desta de estarem juntos é eu poder manter um tamanho só pros cards, porque os dois primeiros são idênticos. Mas o último é somente Mês/Ano. Ai quando eu altero, muda automaticamente o tamanho da largura.

Comment: sabe me dizer como eu poderia ajustar largura x altura desses cards? De forma que mantenha responsividade.

Comment: @WandersonBueno faz assim pra ficar mais fácil de eu te ajudar, cria um Codepen, ou Jsfiddle e coloca o seu código mais atual, com os cards que vc tem etc, ai eu dou uma olhada para vc, mas o ideial é que vc coloque cada grupo de elementos dentro de um célula do grid do próprio Bootstrap. Outra opção é vc abrir uma pergunta nova aqui no site mesmo com o seu código atual e explicando o que precisa, ai eu ou outro usuário pode te ajudar :) Olha isso e me fala que te ajudo